# paperclip removes existing attachment on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

**AR Models**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sponsor
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsor
end

class Sponsor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :logo
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**Controller**

```
def update
  if @post.update(post_params)
    flash[:success] = 'Post update sucessfully'
  else
    flash[:error] = @post.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
    render :edit
  end
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, sponsor_attributes: [:descriptive_text, :logo, :name, :website, :description])
end
```

Here when a `Post` is updated, sponsor also gets updated in nested form.

But while updating if user doesn't choose any image, Paperclip removes existing attachment.

How can we preserve existing attachment if user doesn't select other while updating a record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsor, reject_if: :all_blank
```

---

[**`reject_if`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for).

The problem you have is that, unfortunately, Paperclip is actually quite "dumb" when it comes to accepting data.

As many people send associated data to Paperclip, it basically takes what it's given and builds objects out of it. In your case, it means you're sending blank objects, leading Paperclip to replace your existing attachment with the blank one.

The `reject_if` switch for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is the fix for this -- it allows you to specify any occasions whence Rails will "reject" any nested data, preserving the file you have...

> `reject_if`
>
> Allows you to specify a `Proc` or a `Symbol` pointing to a method that checks whether a record should be built for a certain attribute hash.
>
> The hash is passed to the supplied Proc or the method and it should return either true or false. When no `:reject_if` is specified, a record will be built for all attribute hashes that do not have a _destroy value that evaluates to true.
>
> Passing `:all_blank` instead of a `Proc` will create a proc that will reject a record where all the attributes are blank excluding any value for `_destroy`.

---

The caveat to this would be if you were updating something *other* than the image (I see you have `:descriptive_text`, `:logo`, `:name`, `:website`, `:description`).

In this instance, you'd need to pass the appropriate data to your `Sponsor` model (IE no `logo` param):

```
def post_params
   sponsor_params = [:id, :descriptive_text, :logo, :name, :website, :description]
   sponsor_params -= [:logo] if (action_name == "update") && !params[:post][:sponsor_attributes][:logo]

   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, sponsor_attributes: sponsor_params)
end
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this with the [Paperclip validators](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations), but for now the above should suffice.

---

References:

- [Preventing Paperclip from deleting/overwriting attachments on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911191/preventing-paperclip-from-deleting-overwriting-attachments-on-update)
- [Rails with Paperclip ignore empty attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764426/rails-with-paperclip-ignore-empty-attachments)

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. You saved my day. I have modified `post_params` method in your answer a bit to make it work.